# SQL - Calculate number of days

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I am trying to calculate the number of days customers pay invoices either early or late.

```
select 
    a.Invoice, 
    datediff(day,InvoiceDate,JournalDate) as Days, 
    c.DueDays, 
    c.Description as Terms  

from 
    ArInvoice a 
    Inner Join ArInvoicePay b on a.Invoice = b.Invoice 
    Inner Join TblArTerms c on a.TermsCode = c.TermsCode
```

This is great for customers with a *Date of Invoice* term. The problem is for customers with for instance *60 days end of month*. I am struggling to come up with a way using the `InvoiceDate` and using two other fields `InvDayOfMonth = '31'` and `InvMonths = '2'` to calculate the number of days.

In laymans terms I need to calculate the number of days from the `InvoiceDate` until 31 days, add this to the then multiplied `InvMonth` by 31.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not very clear what Your problem is. Invoice has a date. Then Customer has a property saying how long they can delay the payment. So for example invoice date is 2012.09.15 and customer Delay is 60d. What result would You expect ?

Comment: Is it that if Invoice date is equal to 2012.09.15 and InvMonth = 2, the result You'd need is 2012.10.31 ?

Comment: c# equivalent would look like this :
var date = new DateTime(2012, 09, 15);
var firstDayOfMonth = new DateTime(date.Year, date.Month, 1);
var invMonth = 2;
//Add invMonth 
var temp = firstDayOfMonth.AddMonths(invMonth); //outputs '2012.11.01
var LastDayOfMonth = temp.AddDays(-1);

Comment: @Marty Id expect it to be 2012.11.31  if InvMonth = 1 then i'd expect 2012.11.31

Comment: I already calculate the date diff between invoice and payment date. The DueDays gives me the value of days due on DOI terms, i just need to calculate the number of days of EOM invoices.  The goal to ultimately work out the number of days our customers pay us early/late.  Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

SQL would look like this

```
SELECT 
dateadd(day,-1,
dateadd(month, 2, --Your variable here
--replace getdate with Invoice date, and figure out the 0+month part
convert(DATE, cast(Year(getdate()) as NVARCHAR) + '0'+cast(Month(getdate()) as NVARCHAR) + '01')))
```

Due to Your Comment the answer is simple then

```
SELECT 
dateadd(day,60,InvoiceDate) 
--replace 60 with the number You've already calculated
```

Comment: Were using 2005 not 2008, tried the DATETIME instead and its not happy.

Comment: these functions are SQL 2000 standard. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258863(v=sql.80).aspx
Look for an error elsewhere

Comment: @LewisCooksey Care to explain the symptoms of "not happy"?